# Custom glyph on DataGridView Header

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a **DataGridView** where I would like drawing custom glyph (let's suppose a triangle) on the column header when the user click on it.

I have the property **EnableHeadersVisualStyles** set to **False**.

Do you have any example or suggestions how to reach the desired result? Do I need to inherit from DataGridView, or DataGridViewColumn?

Thank you in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

you need to do a few thing first attach handler to event GridView_CellPainting the inside the event handler do like this

```
void GridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {
                e.PaintBackground( e.ClipBounds, true );
                StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                e.Graphics.DrawString( e.FormattedValue.ToString() this.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush( this.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor ),e.CellBounds, sf );

                             //
                             //Place code to draw your custom gliph
                             //
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

the row "sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;" set text to be painted left alignemet if you need it otherwise change

Answer (score 0):

I have found this helpful. It works perfectly

> If you want the column headers to be perfectly centered, you'll need
>   to disable sorting. Set the SortMode property for the column to
>   "NonSortable". This should prevent space from being reserved for the
>   sort glyph whenever the column text is center or right justified.

From: [How can I center the heading in a column on a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550836/how-can-i-center-the-heading-in-a-column-on-a-datagridview)